# How to use Searchkick gem with acts_as_taggable gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, searchkick

I have Searchkick setup and and everything works. How would i get tags added through acts_as_taggable to show up in the search? So if a user searches for a tag it will show up in the results.

## **Here are my files**

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

   root 'links#index'
   resources :tag

   resources :links do
      collection do
          get 'search'
      end
   end

end
```

**Controller Search Action**

```
def search
    if params[:search].present?
        @links = Link.search(params[:search], page: params[:page], per_page: 15 )
    else
        @links = Link.all
    end
end
```

**Search.html.erb View**

```
<%= render 'shared/tagcloud' %>

<%= will_paginate @link %>

<div id="links-wrapper">
    <%= render partial: "shared/link", collection: @links %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! I had to add this to my Links Model File:

```
def search_data
   attributes.merge(
    tags_name: tags.map(&:name)
   )
end
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you have done as I have a similar "Post" and I am using Acts_as_taggable_on gem for tagging?Basically I want to show the posts related to the tags entered by the user. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is just to use `tag_list` like this:

```
  def search_data
    {
      name: name,
      # description: description.tr("\u0000-\u001f\u007f\u2028",''),
      excerpt: excerpt,
      end_date: end_date,
      start_date: start_date,
      tag: tag_list
    }
  end
```

This works because tag_list outputs an array of tags, so you don't need to map them into an array.